# PHP preg_match_all: Extract comma separated list

Tags: php, regex

I have, for example, the following string:

```
{WIDGET_TEST('abc','456')}
```

I'd like to be able to use preg_match_all to return an array of the comma separated arguments.

Can anybody help me out with the regular expression I need?

I've tried and the following query returns `(a,b)`:

```
preg_match_all('/\([a-zA-Z0-9\',]+\)/', '{WIDGET_TEST(a,b)}', $arguments);
```

But I'm left fighting to get this result as an array, and the regex breaks when I introduce the apostrophes?

EDIT
Using the following:

```
preg_match_all('/(\'[a-zA-Z0-9,]+\')/', '{WIDGET_TEST('variable1','b')}', $arguments);
```

I get:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string ''variable1'' (length=11)
      1 => string ''b'' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string ''variable1'' (length=11)
      1 => string ''b'' (length=3)
```

So believe I am part way there...

Comment: Because of the complexity of the grammar, this cannot be reliably parsed in a single regex without caveats like unescaped `,` inside single quotes etc. I would suggest trimming up to and including the parentheses, and then parsing the parameters separately.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer as I've made progress...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you try the following regex it should work for what you need:

```
preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/', '{WIDGET_TEST(\'variable1\', \'b\')}', $classname);
```

It should return, from the input string, the strings that are constructed from ‘abcdEDFGHJ123’. To put it bluntly, it will return a new result when the string breaks from this makup.