# PHP Preg_Match Extract Comma Seperated Values from String

Tags: php, regex, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP preg_match_all: Extract comma seperated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193176/php-preg-match-all-extract-comma-seperated-list)

I have a string that looks like: `[something ="1,2,3"]` 
I need get everything between the quotes into a string.   I'm sure that preg_match is the way to do this but i'm not sure of the expression to use.

```
$content = [something = "1,2,3"];
$new_string = preg_match('?regex?','$content');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$content = '[something = "1,2,3"]';

if (preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/', $content, $matches)) {
    $matchedContent = $matches[1];
}
```